# facebook share for custom parameters in a link

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to share my custom link on facebook using this javascript function,

```
function postToFacebook(title, summary, image_url, U) 
 {
   window.open('http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id= ' + fb_app_id + '&display=popup&caption=' + title  + '&description='+ summary + '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent('http://facebook.com') + '&link=' + encodeURI(U) + '&picture=' + image_url,'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');
 }
```

In my "U" parameter I have this link => "http://localhost:4000/rings/solitaire-rings/lst?utf8=%E2%9C%93&min_price=&max_price=&name=solitaire-rings&category=rings&fashion_type=false&search=&gallery_order=&new_arrival=&best_seller=&metal_white=on&commit=APPLY"

and when user clicks on the link which is shared on facebook , user should get redirected to this link. forget about root url i.e. localhost:4000, because on production environment its considering required url.

the problem is that whne i am sharing this url on facebook user is getting redirected to "http://localhost:4000/rings/solitaire-rings/lst?utf8", and its not taking care of further parameters which are "%E2%9C%93&min_price=&max_price=&name=solitaire-rings&category=rings&fashion_type=false&search=&gallery_order=&new_arrival=&best_seller=&metal_white=on&commit=APPLY"

basicaaly I supposed to get this URL "http://admin.velvetcase.com/rings/lst?utf8=%E2%9C%93&min_price=&max_price=&name=rings&fashion_type=false&search=&gallery_order=&new_arrival=&best_seller=&search_material_id[]=Diamond&commit=APPLY" , but when I am sharing mu URL on facebook I am getting this one "http://admin.velvetcase.com/rings/lst?utf8=%E2%9C%93&amp%3Bmin_price&amp%3Bmax_price&amp%3Bname=rings&amp%3Bfashion_type=false&amp%3Bsearch&amp%3Bgallery_order&amp%3Bnew_arrival&amp%3Bbest_seller&amp%3Bsearch_material_id[0]=Diamond&amp%3Bcommit=APPLY" , which is not giving e required output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did successfully

```
var sharingUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id="+ facebookAppID +
                 "&link=" + sharingUrl +
                 "&name=" + encodeURIComponent(title) +
                 "&caption=" + encodeURIComponent(caption) +
                 "&description=" + encodeURIComponent(content) +
                 "&picture=" + encodeURIComponent(thumb) +
                 "&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com";
window.open(sharingUrl);
```

For all parameters we need to use `encodeURIComponent`, but I try to not use `encodeURIComponent` for `sharingUrl`, it still works!

Comment: Is it mandatory to send name, caption parameters? because I don't want to send these parameters

Comment: No, it is just optional!

Comment: Hmmm, check your facebook app, it may not allow localhost!